# AFJSONRequestOperation with JSON encoded as NSISOLatin1StringEncoding crashing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I want to use AFNetworking more specifically AFJSONRequestOperation in a project to allow for easy async calls. I quickly tried using the sample code from [AFNetworking GitHub Page](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"App.net Global Stream: %@", JSON);
    } 
    failure:nil];
[operation start];
```

Which works fine, But when I use the URL for MetOffice Datapoint it crashes, I believe this might be because of the encoding type of the JSON feed being `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` which causes a problem with `NSJSONSerialization`

The way I currently handle this is

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:kMetOfficeAllSites encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding error:&error];
NSData *metOfficeData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:metOfficeData options:kNilOptions error:&error]
```

But how do I handle this situation with AFJSONRequestOperation?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Convert your data to NSString using that encoding, and see if it appears to be valid JSON.  If need be you can back-convert to NSData and feed that through the JSON parser (or find a JSON parser than handles NSString).

Comment: I know the JSON is valid, I just don't know how to tell AFJSONRequestOperation to deal with it, as it NSISOLatin1StringEncoding and will not work with NSJSONSerialization

Comment: So AFJSONRequestOperation has no way to be aware of the encoding of the data?  In theory, the encoding is supposed to be transmitted with the data, and should be available for inspection.

Comment: Thats really my question, how do I make AFJSONRequestOperation deal with it. I don't think the encoding type is transmitted in the header.

Comment: Then maybe you can't use AFJSONRequestOperation.

Comment: `AFJSONRequestOperation` is open source, so, go and fix it. Somewhere it's using `NSJSONSerialization`, and you already know how to change the code.

Comment: Maybe you should try to use the XML version of MetOffice Datapoint, which embed the encoding. No idea if it'll work